# How to compile .Fla and .as files

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash, fla

I have downloaded a program called "Piecemaker". Its a flash based image/album slider. Package came with a .fla file and some .as files. I want to make couple of small changes (change the hard coded text) in the code and then rebuild the .swf file. Can you please tell me how I can do that? I am not a flash/flex developer. I am a Java developer and looking for some guidance on the software I should download and how to compile/build.

Link to Piecemaker software: http://bit.ly/Piecemaker2

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the fla file in Flash Authoring environment, change the things you want to change (F9 shows code window, look for frames in the timeline that contain code) and re-publish the file.

If this does not answer the question, please give a few more details of what you want to do or where you stuck.

Comment: Can you please name one of the flash authoring tools (even if its a Trail copy that's fine). Thank you.

Comment: Also, as an FYI, if you don't have the Flash Pro IDE, Adobe offers a 60-day trial of it on their site. Works great for quick needs like this.

Comment: Thanks. The file is really big. I will download and try it.